# Install xmltodict in SSIS project

Tags: python, visual-studio, ssis

I an using Visual Studio on an MS Sevrer and have an SSIS project in which I intend to do ETL using Python. I have Python installed in Visual Studio along with the right libraries. I have run a simple query on SSMS:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
  @language =N'Python',
  @script=N'print("Welcome to Python in SQL Server")'
GO
```

and it works too along with other imports like pandas and etree.

I am getting the error of '`No module named xmltodict`' even though `xmltodict` is installed. It seems like SSIS prosject in Visual Studio is not detecting the installed library.

Can you please help med figure out what is causing this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this blog post ([Scraping data with SSIS and Python](https://www.bi4all.pt/en/news/en-blog/scraping-data-with-ssis-and-python/)). In this reference, a python interpreter is installed on the same development environment where VS is running.

It may not be enough to have the setting switched on on the database level alone. What version of SSIS/VS are you working with?

Comment: Thank you, @plditallo. It worked with navigating to Scripts folder and installing the library there.